# Is there a way to duplicate data prior to posting to an SQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

Is there a way to push data to two fields in a table if a check box is clicked?

So in English, as a pure hypothetical I have six fields and a check box in two rows. First row, field one is name, second is address, third is email.

What I want to do is if the information is to be transferred from left to right upon posting, a person needs to check a box.

The table would have six fields.

```
name, address, email, name2, address2, email2.
```

So what would happen is that data that would post in name would also post in name2, as long as the check box is checked.

Is this possible in PHP?

Ok, well since people want a script to look at for an example, here... I figure it be easier to write up a generic script than to post what I'm working on. Sorry, thought I'd make it easier for people here.

```
<?php

require_once('connectvars.php');
        $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
        or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
$output_form = 'yes';

echo '<div id="postwrap">'
?>

<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Document Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/postie.css" />

</head>

<body>
<div id="title">
    <h3 id="NCMR2">Document Test</h3>
</div>
<?php
//Post Data
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $ab = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ab']));
    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime ($_POST['date']))));
    $part = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['part']));
    $rev = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['rev']));
    $partdesc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['partdesc']));
    $ncmrqty = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ncmrqty']));
    $ab2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ab']));
    $date2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime ($_POST['date']))));
    $part2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['part']));
    $rev2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['rev']));
    $partdesc2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['partdesc']));
    $ncmrqty2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ncmrqty']));


    $output_form = 'no';

    if (empty($ab) || empty($date) || empty($part) || empty($partdesc)){

// We know at least one of the input fields is blank 
echo '<div id="alert">';
echo 'Please fill out all of the required NCMR information.<br />';
    echo '</div>';

}
    $output_form = 'yes';

}

//Access the Database
    if (!empty($ab) && !empty($date) && !empty($pod)) {
        $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
        or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

    $query = "INSERT INTO ncmr (ab, date, part, rev, partdesc, ncmrqty, ab2, date2, part2, rev2, partdesc2, ncmrqty2)

    VALUES ('$ab', '$date', '$part', '$rev', '$partdesc', '$ncmrqty', '$ab2', '$date2', '$part2', '$rev2', '$partdesc2', '$ncmrqty2')";

    mysqli_query($dbc,$query)
        or die ('Data not inserted.');

            // Clear the form data
    $ab = "";
    $date = "";
    $part = "";
    $rev = "";
    $partdesc = "";
    $ncmrqty = "";
    $ab2 = "";
    $date2 = "";
    $part2 = "";
    $rev2 = "";
    $partdesc2 = "";
    $ncmrqty2 = "";


      // Confirm success with the user
    echo '<tr><td class="thank">';
    echo '<p>Thank you for adding the NCRM, the correct person will be informed.</p>';
    echo '<p><a href="post.php">&lt;&lt; Back to the form</a></p>';
        $output_form = 'no';
    echo '</td></tr>';

    mysqli_close($dbc);
}
  if ($output_form == 'yes') {
echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>";
        echo '<fieldset>';
        //Part, Rev, Part Description, NCMR Qty
            echo '<div id="box1">';
                echo '<div id="ab"><span class="b">Added By:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ab" value="" /></div>';
                echo '<div id="date"><span class="b">Date Filed:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="date" value="" /></div>';
                echo '<div id="part"><span class="b">Part Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="part" value="" /></div>';
                echo '<div id="rev"><span class="b">Part Revision:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="rev" value="" /></div>';
                echo '<div id="partdesc"><span class="b">Part Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea name="partdesc" rows="4" cols="22" ></textarea></div>';
                echo '<div id="ncmrqty"><span class="b">NCMR Qty:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ncmrqty" value="" /></div>';
            echo '</div>';


            echo '<div id="box2">';
                echo '<div id="ab2"><span class="b">Added By:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ab2" value="" /></div>';
                echo '<div id="date2"><span class="b">Date Filed:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="date2" value="" /></div>';
                echo '<div id="part2"><span class="b">Part Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="part2" value="" /></div>';
                echo '<div id="rev2"><span class="b">Part Revision:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="rev2" value="" /></div>';
                echo '<div id="partdesc2"><span class="b">Part Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea name="partdesc2" rows="4" cols="22" ></textarea></div>';
                echo '<div id="ncmrqty2"><span class="b">NCMR Qty:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ncmrqty2" value="" /></div>';
            echo '</div>';
                    echo '<div id="button3"><input type="submit" value="Submit NCMR" name="submit" /></div>';
            echo '</div>';
    echo '</fieldset>';
echo '</form>';
    }
echo '</div>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible in PHP. A more detailed answer would require example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a name to the checkbox, say "***duplicateBox***", and have its value set to `1` when checked.

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name2 = $_POST['name2'];
    $address2 = $_POST['address2'];
    $email2 = $_POST['email2'];
    $duplicate = $_POST['duplicateBox'];


    if($duplicate == 1)
    {
        $name2 = $name;
        $address2 = $address;
        $email2 = $email;
    }

    $insert = "INSERT INTO `table` (name,address,email,name2,address2,email2) VALUES ('$name','$address','$email','$name2','$address2','$email2')";
    mysql_query($insert)or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: How would this work with a checkbox? The only reason I ask is because it looks as if it takes into consideration a duplicate, but it doesn't show how the duplicate checkbox works.

Comment: @enam, thanks, this is greatly appreciated. Just one last question. If this is inside a larger form, would it be better to encompass the entire thing in brackets or and have an else after so it would either post the duplicate or go normal if the checkbox isn't checked?

Comment: Dear Matt, ALL CREDIT GOES TO Emil Larsson. Who actually post this Answer....About your question: I think better Emil answer it and modify the code accordingly(if required)...

Comment: @MattRidge, say that this checkbox is in your form:
<input type="checkbox" name="duplicateBox" value="1" />

$duplicate will take the value of this checkbox, and if it is 1 (checked) the values in name,address and email will be duplicated and if it is not it will just skip that little bit of code. I added extra variables for name2 etc at the top.

Comment: @EmilLarsson, wouldn't it be more advantageous to put the $insert line into the brackets and then put an else{} so that if duplicate == 1 do do this, otherwise proceed as normal or am I oversimplifying things?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible (kind of) to do that using conditional statement. 
It's not that you are posting duplicate data, but duplicating data that is already posted to your PHP script.
Very simple example:

```
$fieldsToDuplicate = array('name', 'address', 'email');
if (isset($_POST['checkbox'] && 1 == $_POST['checkbox']) { 
    foreach ($fieldsToDuplicate as $value)
    {
        $_POST[$value.'2'] = $_POST[$value];
    } 
}
```

Though have in mind that you should validate & filter input you got from the user before actually manipulating/inserting to database :)

It is also possible to have duplicate fields in HTML and duplicate data with Javascript, and then handle it in PHP without any conditions.